# Meaning of "his junior" in "a Ukrainian model 30 years his junior"?

Tags: comprehension

Example with [context](http://news.yahoo.com/prominent-russian-opposition-figure-boris-nemtsov-shot-dead-223512822.html):

> The investigators said they also were considering whether there was "personal enmity" toward Nemtsov in his domestic life. State-controlled and Kremlin-friendly TV gave considerable attention to Nemtsov's companion, identifying her as a Ukrainian model **30 years his junior** and showing photos of her in alluring poses. The Investigative Committee said the pair was headed for Nemtsov's apartment.

Okay. She was a Ukrainian model who was 30 years old. But I don't understand the *his junior* part.

Comment: It's not saying that she's 30 years old at all.  "His junior" means "younger than him"... so if he's 50 and she's 30 years his junior, that makes her 20.

Comment: @Catija You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @pyobum meh. I always feel weird answering without having sources... but I'm a native speaker, so I'm not sure how necessary they are.

Comment: @Catija The only source you need here is a dictionary definition.

Comment: from local Russian news, she's 23 years old. He was 55.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The term *his junior* (or *her junior*) is a term that relates one person's age to the others.

**Junior** in general [means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/junior):

> younger in age

In your example:

> Ukrainian model 30 years his junior

It does not mean that she's 30 years old.  It means that she's 30 years younger than he is.

So, if he's 50 years old and she's 30 years his junior, that means that she's 20 years old.

Comment: Keep in mind this also would apply to the term *senior*. In this case, he is *30 years her senior*.